# Recycling IIS 7 app pool at specific time

Tags: iis, application-pool

We are getting an error when we try to set it to a specific time every 7 days at a specific time. The doc says it is possible by using the optional [d] argument. We want to recycle every 7 days at 3 am.
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754494(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754494%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Command : 
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd set apppool /apppool.name: TempPool /+recycli
ng.periodicRestart.schedule.[value='7.03:00:00']

### Error Message:

### Application Pools

There was an error while performing this operation.

Details:

Timespan value must be between 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 seconds inclusive, with a granularity of 60 seconds

---

Comment: Does it need to be set via command-line?  If you have access to IIS manager, you can set this pretty easily in IIS, in the app pool config.

Comment: I tried that it gave the same error. Not taking the optional d parameter for day.

Answer (score 3):

Although this question is a bit expired, but i faced it yesterday when i was writing some c# codes to manipulate an application pool programmly.

I found the sample for schedules at doc in following link which reads "adding an application pool... then set the application pool to daily recycle at 3:00 A.M.", which means we could not specify a fixed time span for recycling by add a schedule.
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/periodicrestart/schedule/add#006

That's why it throws the exception to ask a time span under 23:59:59.

When you want specify a fixed time span for recycling, you should use time property from periodicRestart level.
See this doc for samples for various ways to target your requirement.
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/periodicrestart#005

```
// add schedule to recycle at 3 am every day
appPool.Recycling.PeriodicRestart.Schedule.Clear(); 
appPool.Recycling.PeriodicRestart.Schedule.Add(new TimeSpan(3, 0, 0));

// set to recycle every 3 hours
appPool.Recycling.PeriodicRestart.Time = new TimeSpan(3, 0, 0);
```